# Why is the std::bitset constructor with an unsigned long long argument not marked as explicit?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, bitset, unsigned-long-long-int, explicit-constructor

The Standard Library class template `std::bitset<N>` has a constructor (C++11 and onwards, `unsigned long` argument before C++11)

```
constexpr bitset(unsigned long long) noexcept
```

Contrary to many best-practice guidelines, this single-argument constructor is not marked as `explicit`. What is the rationale behind this?

Comment: The C++ standard library has a fair share of questionable design decisions.

Comment: @n.m. Sure, so I am looking for an answer to determine if I should submit a defect report for this one ;-)

Comment: As a _guess_, because the operators are not overloaded to accept unsigned integers, and this way code like `mybitset |= 0x4;` should compile.

Comment: It *might* make sense for `std::bitset<32> bs = 0x0FFFFFFF;` to compile. Anyway, I'm doubtful that they'd make it explicit at this point - breaks too much code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Explicit construction

The main objection against an `explicit` constructor is that copy-initialization from unsigned integers no longer works

```
constexpr auto N = 64;
std::bitset<N> b(0xDEADC0DE);  // OK, direct initialization
std::bitset<N> b = 0xDEADC0DE; // ERROR, copy initialization cannot use explicit constructors
```

Since `std::bitset<N>` is meant as a generalization of `unsigned int`, the constructor was probably made implicit to facilitate adapting existing C-style bit-twiddling code based on raw `unsigned int`. Making the constructor `explicit` would have broken much existing code (and adding it now will equally break much existing code).

**UPDATE**: doing some Standard archeology, I found [**N0624**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1995/N0624.asc) from January 1995 that proposed to add the then brand-new keyword `explicit` to all single-argument constructors in the pre-Standard Library draft. This was put to a vote at a meeting in March 1995 (Austin). As documented in [**N0661**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1995/N0661.pdf), the `unsigned long` constructor for `bitset` was not made `explicit` (unanimous vote, but without motivation).

### Mixed-mode bit-twiddling

However, even though `bitset` is easily initialized from `unsigned long`, there is otherwise incomplete mixed-mode setwise operations (`&`, `|` or `^`):

```
 constexpr auto N = 512;
 std::bitset<N> b = 0xDEADC0DE; // OK
 std::bitset<N> c = b & 0xFFFF; // ERROR, cannot deduce template arguments for rhs
```

This could be remedied by proposing overloaded operators to support mixed-mode bit-twiddling:

```
 // @ from { &, |, ^ }

 template<std::size_t N> 
 bitset<N> operator@(unsigned long long lhs, const bitset<N>& rhs)

 template<std::size_t N> 
 bitset<N> operator@(const bitset<N>& lhs, unsigned long long rhs)
```

### Overloaded operators as member functions

The schizophrenic nature of `std::bitset` with respect to mixed-mode functionality is also present in the `operator==` and `operator!=`. These are member functions that have implicit conversion on their rhs arguments, but not on their lhs argument (the `this` pointer, which is subject to template argument deduction). This leads to the following:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    constexpr auto N = 64;
    constexpr std::bitset<N> b = 0xDEADC0DE; // OK, copy initialization

    std::cout << (b == 0xDEADC0DE);     // OK, implicit conversion on rhs
    std::cout << (0xDEADC0DE == b);     // ERROR, no implicit conversion on lhs
}
```

The origins of this behavior stem from the 1992 proposal [**N0128**](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1992/WG21%201992/X3J16_92-0051%20WG21_N0128.pdf). The timing of that proposal, which largely locked in the functionality of the future `std::bitset`, was prior to function templates having non-type template parameters. The only feasible workaround at the time was to make all overloaded operators member functions instead of non-member functions. This was never changed later on when more advanced template technology became available (see also [**this Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26089156/819272) for why this might break code).

Comment: `b & 0xFFFF` [doesn't work anyway](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0ef8a78e3ed0272).