# Why does the C++ standard specifies a destructor for std::bitset::reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, destructor, std-bitset

I am wondering why [`std::bitset::reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/reference) and [`std::vector<bool>::reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference) specifies an explicit destructor (not compiler generated one). Because, for example, [`boost::dynamic_bitset::reference`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) does not seem to specify such a destructor.

Comment: Someone wrote this up in the 1990's, and nobody has proposed to change it since? No other reason, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because the Standard mentions `~reference()` as a destructor, does not mean it has to be user-provided as a no-op `{}` (which is how [**libstdc++**](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/bitset) and [**SGI/STL**](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/bitset) do it). It could also be user-declared as `=default`, or even left defined implicitly (which is how [**libc++**](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/__bit_reference) does it). Regardless, the Standard could be updated to have this explicit mention of the destructor removed. You could file an editorial change (I don't think it warrants a real proposal).

As noted by @BoPersson in the comments, `std::bitset` is a very old component of the Standard Library. Many of its features (implicit constructor from unsigned integer, member instead of non-member `operator==`) pre-date the language standardization in 1998. Shameless plugs: see e.g. [**this Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25833391/819272) for more discussion how this might have arisen, and [**this Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26089156/819272) for why it might break code when this would be fixed.

`<rant mode>`

The best way out of the legacy of `std::bitset` would be a clean break in `namespace experimental`. Preferably, this would also solve the mixed abstraction of `std::bitset`, which at the same time tries to be a space optimized version of `array<bool>` as well as a `set<int>`. Ideally, there would be a proposal for a `bool_array<N>` and a `bounded_int_set<N>` that provided these abstractions. Similarly, `bool_vector<Alloc>` (currently known as `vector<bool, Alloc>`) and `int_set<Alloc>` (currently a mixture of `boost::dynamic_bitset` and `boost::container::flat_set<int, Alloc>`) could be defined.

`</rant mode>`